# IntelliJ Git plugin error during cloning the files

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I would like to ask you, how to solve problem, when I want clone the project in intelliJ 2016.2 and there is an exception "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

When I clone using Eclipse, everything is fine. I know that I am using cacerts for authenticate during this process. I suppose Eclipse uses cacerts that I have in my Java security folder. But how to "give" the cacerts to IntelliJ or Git?

Thank you.